# Plugins in Jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, css-transitions

I am using Jquery Ui plugins  **jquery-1.3.2.min.js** and **jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js**
and now i want to use animate() and tootip() methods  to my code. Is these 2 plugins are sufficient  to work with these. please let me know if any further things i need to add to use animate() and tootip() methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need tooltip [dependent](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip#Depends_on)  and I dont know exactly what you made using in `jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js` because you made it. As far as `.animate` is concerned you need the `jquery-1.3.2.min.js` which you have

Comment: Is that **jquery.dimensions.js** plugin used for tooltip